# Question got reputation for 2 upvotes but showing 1 upvote in the post

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, votes, reputation

I see a [user](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/29365/kashmir23) posted a [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45644/29292) and got reputation for [two upvotes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/29365/kashmir23?tab=reputation&sort=post). On checking the question, it shows only one upvote. He also didn't get any downvote(s).

As per the reputation the question should shown with two upvotes but it shown as one. How is this possible?

On his profile it shows he is *(unregistered)* user, is the reason for the conflict. Some one can explain the exact thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user's question **did indeed get a downvote**, as can be seen by any user with the privileges for showing the vote differences on question:

[image]

The reason he didn't get a reputation change from the downvote but only from the two upvotes is likely that **the downvote was the first vote** he got and since a user's reputation can't sink below 1, it resulted in **no reputation changes** for him at all.

Comment: indeed, http://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/45644/timeline shows the downvote on Jan 1 and the upvotes on Jan 5 and 9.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.